# SAP B1 Query - Is The document being added or updated?

Tags: sapb1

Using SAP B1's extra SQL syntax is there a way to access whether the current document is in add mode or update mode?  I'm using this query to populate a user defined field with a user defined value.  I need to adjust the logic depending on whether it is a new document or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it using the normal UID syntax. $[$UID]  In this case the OK button that changes to add / update when typing into a document is 1.  You can save the following into a query and it will return the text in that button.

```
SELECT $[$1.0.0]
```

After that it's just a matter of using the CASE statement to check if it is equal to 'Update' or 'Add' or 'OK'.